# count number of occurrences in list by dict with key and value

Tags: python

With a dictionary, I am trying to find if the key occurs as many times (or more) as the value. So, for example I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
expected = { "blue": 2, "red": 1 }
```

and a list that looks like this:

```
results = [ 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red' ]
```

I need to see if blue occurs 2 or more times and if red occurs 1 or more times.
What is the best way to go about this? I have tried:

```
for k, v in expected.items():
  if results.count(k) >= v:
    // return
```

but this will match on either key and not strictly check the entire list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need them *all* to be at least as large.  That means that you have to complete the loop before you can return success.  Any failure means that you can return immediately.

```
for k, v in expected.items():
    if results.count(k) < v:
        return False

return True
```

Or, use the `all` function to put this into a single line:

```
return all(results.count(k) >= v for k, v in expected.items() )
```